# pyinstaller and Pyomo and also SCIP

Tags: python, pyomo, scip

I would like to package (using `pyinstaller`) my optimizer program that uses `Pyomo` and SCIP. I keep getting `pyomo.environ` import errors and have been experimenting with hidden imports.

I saw [this](https://groups.google.com/g/pyomo-forum/c/n1Hn8q7Qwmw) and was surprised, but I tried it anyway. It seems like it should go in a file. I tried it and as expected doesn't get everything and so the command just keeps getting bigger. I am using [SCIP](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scip) and so I will have problems there. I heard that you can add the executable to the optimizer, but I have no idea where `conda` put that executable.

Can we get a good solution to creating executables (with the extra folders and not just one file) using `pyinstaller` and featuring `Pyomo`? It needs an added focus on how to, exactly, add the optimizers (like SCIP)?

Comment: Would you please, can you solve your issue?